# Auto add wiki pages to sidebar menu in tikiwiki

Tags: menu, sidebar, wiki

I'm running a Tikiwiki (16.2) now and here are my problem:

Every time a wiki is created, I always has to add that page to the sidebar menu manually.

Is there anyway for the new wiki pages will be automatically added the the sidebar? Just like the sidebar of the MindTouch.

I tried Structure but look like It's not the way.

Thanks,
Trinh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking deeper into the documentations, I can archived what I want:

1. Create a structure (let call it A)
2. Create a module that pull information from structure A
3. Assign the menu to the sidebar location (left).
4. Create a first page and assign it to structure A.
5. Child pages will be added to the structure automatically

You can also do the same with Catogories.